# How to merge to tables into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I had a two tables in MYSQL namely:

```
T1 T2
```

Now here is my problem. the T1 contains:

```
id = 1
name = name1
fname = fname1
SIRB no. = SIRB123456789
SIRB expiry = 2016 June 01

id = 2
name = name2
fname = fname2
SIRB no. = SIRB12345
SIRB expiry = 2016 June 01

id = 3
name = name3
fname = fname3
SIRB no. = SIRBof3
SIRB expiry = 2016 June 01
```

and for the second table:

```
id = 1
name = name1
fname = fname1
VISA no. = null
VISA expiry = null

id = 2
name = name2
fname = fname2
VISA no. = null
VISA expiry = null

id = 3
name = name3
fname = fname3
VISA no. = VISA123
VISA expiry = 2016 June 1
```

and my problem is I want to merge all off this table into one so my final table would be like:

```
id = 1
name = name1
fname = fname1
SIRB no. = SIRB123456789
SIRB expiry = 2016 June 01
VISA no. = null
VISA expiry = null

id = 2
name = name2
fname = fname2
SIRB no. = SIRB12345
SIRB expiry = 2016 June 01
VISA no. = null
VISA expiry = null

id = 3
name = name3
fname = fname3
SIRB no. = SIRBof3
SIRB expiry = 2016 June 01
VISA no. = VISA123
VISA expiry = 2016 June 1
```

assume that this is on one table and only three columns (cant upload pictures right now so please bear with me).

Comment: I think this layout is much more readable then yours. Please don't touch it again.

Comment: sorry just a newbie here

Answer (score 0):

You create a table with the columns you want. Then either first insert data directly from one table and then update the rest if the columns from the other, or create a select query that already joins the data.

The exact query depends on how you can join the tables. I assume the I'd fields aren't a match, so you probably have to use the name, if it is unique.